# How to assign a column name of Spring Model from a variable

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a Sring hibernate Model as follows

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "client")
public class Category {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;

private String type;
...
...
...
```

I have some 50 columns. Now while inseting a new row into this table, how can i give the column name dynamically,

```
Client client = new Client();
String columnName = "type";
```

How do I update client model with the column name given in string columnName?

Comment: What is your question? please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the values for columns dynamically, you can use Java reflection concept. 
Have a look at the Java reflection concept, following links may be helpful

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/fields.html

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-get-and-set-a-field-using-reflection.html

Comment: It probably won't actually work. JPA builds bindings at load time and won't re-scan if you somehow manage to screw around with the field annotations at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

For updating the table, we need to get the the field from the category Object and set the new value for that and finally invoke the save() method. 
But if you want to set the field values dynamically, then you need to find the the attributes present inside the Category object using Java reflection methods. Use methods provided by **Field** object in java and use them. Then after getting the filed invoke the set method of the same and update the value. 
`Category.class.getDeclaredFields()`.